# Nodelet error while launching pcl_to_scan launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, nodelet, pointcloud-to-laserscan, nodelets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I want to launch the following file to convert pointcloud to laserscan:

```
<launch>

<!-- Do whatever you need to do to publish /cam3d/depth/points -->



<!-- nodelet manager -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_manager" output="screen" respawn="true" args="manager"/>


<!-- throttling -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pointcloud_throttle" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle nodelet_manager" respawn="true">
    <param name="max_rate" value="20.0"/>
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="/cam3d/depth/points"/>
    <remap from="cloud_out" to="cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>

<!-- Fake Laser -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="fake_laser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan nodelet_manager" respawn="true">
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/your_frame_id"/>
    <param name="min_height" value="-0.15"/><!-- Or any other value that suits you etter -->
    <param name="max_height" value="0.15"/><!-- Or any other value that suits you etter -->
    <remap from="cloud" to="/cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>

  <!-- Fake Laser (narrow one, for localization -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="my_laser_narrow" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan nodelet_manager" respawn="true">
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/your_frame_id"/>
    <param name="min_height" value="-0.025"/><!-- Or any other value that suits you etter -->
    <param name="max_height" value="0.025"/><!-- Or any other value that suits you etter -->
    <remap from="cloud" to="/cloud_throttled"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="/narrow_scan"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

However, whenever I try to launch this file, I get the following error:

```
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu-ros:53686/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /fake_laser/max_height
 * /fake_laser/min_height
 * /fake_laser/output_frame_id
 * /my_laser_narrow/max_height
 * /my_laser_narrow/min_height
 * /my_laser_narrow/output_frame_id
 * /pointcloud_throttle/max_rate
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /
    fake_laser (nodelet/nodelet)
    my_laser_narrow (nodelet/nodelet)
    nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    pointcloud_throttle (nodelet/nodelet)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
**ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nodelet/nodelet]: can't locate node [nodelet] in package [nodelet]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nodelet/nodelet]: can't locate node [nodelet] in package [nodelet]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nodelet/nodelet]: can't locate node [nodelet] in package [nodelet]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nodelet/nodelet]: can't locate node [nodelet] in package [nodelet]**
No processes to monitor
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
```

I don't know if I installed nodelet correctly. I need some guidance to troubleshoot these problems:

**ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nodelet/nodelet]: can't locate node [nodelet] in package [nodelet]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nodelet/nodelet]: can't locate node [nodelet] in package [nodelet]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nodelet/nodelet]: can't locate node [nodelet] in package [nodelet]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nodelet/nodelet]: can't locate node [nodelet] in package [nodelet]**

Any help will be greately appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73741/nodelet-error-while-launching-pcl_to_scan-launch-file./) by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) on ROS Answers with karma: 181 on 2013-08-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turned out that the default nodelet package installation is enough. You shouldn't download nodelet from the source.

---

Originally posted by [mozcelikors](https://answers.ros.org/users/5390/mozcelikors/) with karma: 181 on 2013-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1